# Как вставить значение переменной внутрь строки?

Tags: php, ооп, синтаксический-анализ, классы

Пишу класс соединения с базой, в котором есть метод подключения, выборки из таблицы, вставки в таблицу новых данных.

Со вставкой возникла проблема: появляется ошибка следующего характера:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$rowNews' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sait12.loc\controller.php on line 24

Я так понял, что это просто синтаксическая ошибка, что-то с кавычками, наверное. Пробовал и в двойных, и без них вообще — не помогает.

Подскажите, в чём может быть дело, или научите как найти, что не так.

Код класса:

```
class DB_connect {
    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $baza = 'moya2';
    protected $user = 'admin123';
    protected $pass = '123';

        protected function __construct() {
            $connect = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
            mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';"); 
            mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';"); 
            mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';");
            mysql_select_db($this->baza);
        }

        public function getArticles() {
            self::__construct();
            $row_articles = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM articles');
            return $row_articles;
        }

        public function insert($rowNews) {
            self::__construct();
            $addNews = "INSERT INTO articles (title, title_en, text, author, hashteg) VALUES('"$rowNews['title']"', '"$rowNews['title_en']"', '"$rowNews['text']"', '"$rowNews['author']"', '"$rowNews['hashteg']"')";
            $result = mysql_query($addNews) or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_close(self::__construct()->$connect);
        }
}
```

Доработал немного код...попытался добавить некую фильтрацию данных на входе и воспользовался конкатенацией. Народ если у кого будет время и желание гляньте код. В правильном ли направлении я вообще двигаюсь? Есть конечно очень сильное ощущение что операции с базой типа выбрать, взять, вставить, обновить, удалить должны быть в отдельном классе. Так ли это?)) заранее спасибо за ответы...

```
class DB_connect {

    /*Задаю свойства класса*/

    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $baza = 'moya2';
    protected $user = 'admin123';
    protected $pass = '123';
    private $connect = null; /*Правильно ли так задавать свойство для соединения с базой?*/

    /*Конструктор для подключения к базе данных*/

        public function __construct() {
            $this->connect = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
            mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';"); 
            mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';"); 
            mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';");
            mysql_select_db($this->baza);
        }

        /*Метод закрытия соединения с базой данных*/

        public function Close() {
            if($this->connect) {
                mysql_close($this->connect);
                echo 'Соединение с базой данных закрыто';
            }
        }

        /*Метод получения данных из таблицы articles*/

        public function getArticles() {
            self::__construct();
            $row_articles = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM articles');
            return $row_articles;
            self::Close();
        }

        /*Метод вставки статьи в таблицу articles*/

        public function insert($rowNews) {
            $rowNews = filter_var_array($rowNews);/*Попытка фильтрации входных данных*/
            self::__construct();
            $addNews = "INSERT INTO articles (title, title_en, text, author, hashteg) VALUES('".$rowNews['title']."', '".$rowNews['title_en']."', '".$rowNews['text']."', '".$rowNews['author']."', '".$rowNews['hashteg']."')";
            $result = mysql_query($addNews) or die(mysql_error());
            self::Close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Вы неправильно строки объединяете, потому и ругается.

Несколько решений:

**Первое** - встраиваем массив в строку:

```
$a = array(
    'abc' => 'csa',
);
echo "arr: $a[abc]\n"; // arr: csa
```

Т.е. никаких кавычек в массиве, никаких склеивания строк вида `"строка" $param`. Правда, с одинарными кавычками (`'a = $a'`) это не работает и будет выведено все строкой (т.е. выведет `a = $a`). Для вашего кода:

```
$addNews = "INSERT INTO articles (title, title_en, text, author, hashteg) VALUES('$rowNews[title]', '$rowNews[title_en]', '$rowNews[text]', '$rowNews[author]', '$rowNews[hashteg]')";
```

**Второе** - конкатенация строк:

```
$a = 'qwerty';
echo "a = " . $a; // a = qwerty
```

Для вашего кода:

```
$addNews = "INSERT INTO articles (title, title_en, text, author, hashteg) VALUES('" . $rowNews['title'] . "', '" . $rowNews['title_en'] . "', '" . $rowNews['text'] . "', '" . $rowNews['author'] . "', '" . $rowNews['hashteg'] . "')";
```

**Третье** - использование `sprintf`:

```
$a = 'qwe';
$b = 'asd';
sprintf('a = %s, b = %s and a = %s', $a, $b, $a); // a = qwe, b = asd and a = qwe
sprintf('a = %1$s, b = %2$s and a = %1$s', $a, $b); // a = qwe, b = asd and a = qwe
```

Для вашего кода:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO articles (title, title_en, text, author, hashteg) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')";
$addNews = sprintf($sql, $rowNews['title'], $rowNews['title_en'], $rowNews['text'], $rowNews['author'], $rowNews['hashteg']);
```

**P.S.**: для вашего кода ни один из вариантов не является правильным из-за того, что не проверяются входные значения (читайте про sql-инъекции)

Answer (score 5):

конкатенация строк (и строковых значений переменных) в *php* осуществляется точками:

```
"какая-то строка" . "ещё строка" . $var . "и ещё строка"
```

в приложении к вашему коду:

```
"какая-то строка" . $rowNews['title'] . "ещё строка"
```

Comment: Буду пробовать все что описали Выше и обязательно попробую сделать что-нибудь для предотвращения SQL инъекций...позже отпишусь что получилось...

Answer (score 4):

```
    $addNews = "INSERT INTO articles (title, title_en, text, author, hashteg) VALUES('".$rowNews['title']."', '".$rowNews['title_en']."', '".$rowNews['text']."', '".$rowNews['author']."', '".$rowNews['hashteg']."')";

Это самый простой вариант. Есть ещё sql инъекции. Этот вариант от них не защищает
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно писать так `... , "'{$rowNews['title_en']}'", ...`

Comment: Добавил то что получилось выше в коде...по поводу функции filter_var_array подскажите...она вроде как фильтрует массив во входных параметрах...все верно?