# Переменная PHP внутри запроса MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Проблема заключается в выводе переменной `$set_name` внутри MySQLi запроса не в том виде, как того хотелось бы.

`$set_name` в данном примере равно `'name = "John"'`, но в MySQL запросе, вероятно, выводится в другом виде и запрос, соответственно, не выполняется.
Если же переменную `$set_name` заменить на её значение (`name = "John"`), то запрос выполняется...

```
$name = 'John';
if(empty($name)) { 
  $set_name = '';
} else {
  $set_name = ' name = "'.$name.'"';
}
$update = $mysqli->query('UPDATE table SET $set_name WHERE id = 1');
```

Comment: Значит вместо внесения информации в базу сделайте распечатку получающегося запроса и посмотрите что в нем не так. А вообще использовать подставляемый в запрос текст не хорошо. Лучше использовать привязываемые переменные http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Вы не правильно работаете со строками, см. мой [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436010/5079) к дубликату, там приведены основные примеры того, как можно склеивать строки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данные в запрос надо передавать только через специальные маркеры, которые называются параметрами или плейсхолдерами. Например, посмотрите в сторону [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
<?php
/* Выполнение запроса с привязкой PHP переменных */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
FROM fruit
WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: *но так делать плохо* - вы бы написали, почему так делать плохо. Раз человек так делает, значит он этого не знает. А раз не знает, то может пренебречь вашим советом, т.к. его код как бы "проще"

Answer (score 3):

Ваш вариант опасен внедрением [SQL-инъекций](http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php). Переменные стОит вставлять в запрос только при условии экранирования значений и только тогда, когда другого варианта нет. В качестве "другого варианта" *следует использовать* плейсхолдеры и подготовленные запросы. Для используемого вами mysqli и в рамках вашего примера это будет выглядеть так:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE table SET name = ? WHERE id = 1');
$stmt->bind_param('s', 'John');
$result = $stmt->execute();
if (!$result) throw new Exception('SQL error: ' . $mysqli->error, $mysqli->errno);
```

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно сказано в соседнем ответе, данные в запрос надо передавать только через специальные маркеры, которые называются параметрами или плейсхолдерами. В Mysqli таким маркером является знак вопроса.

В самых последних версях РНР (8.2)можно использовать либо такой код

```
$name = 'John';
$id = 1;
$mysqli->execute_query('UPDATE table SET name=? WHERE id = ?', [$name, $id]);
```

либо такой (PHP >=8.1)

```
$name = 'John';
$id = 1;
$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE table SET name=? WHERE id = ?')->execute([$name, $id]);
```

Если версия совсем старая, то использовать код из соседнего ответа

Соответственно, для частного случая приведенного в вопросе

```
$name = 'John';
$id = 1;

$set = [];
$params = [];
if(!empty($name)) { 
    $set[] = 'name = ?';
    $params[] = $name;
}
if ($set) {
    $sql = 'UPDATE table SET '.implode(',', $set).' WHERE id = ?';
    $params[] = $id;
    $mysqli->prepare($sql)->execute($params);
}
```