# wordpress callback вызвать функцию с параметрами

Tags: wordpress

Есть вот такой код:

```
// Заголовок
add_settings_field(
    'title_element',
    'Заголовок',
    'title_callback',
    'about_options',
    'about_section'
);
// Подзаголовок
add_settings_field(
    'subtitle_element',
    'Подзаголовок',
    'subtitle_callback',
    'about_options',
    'about_section'
);
```

После него идет вот такой код

```
// Заголовок
function title_callback() {
    echo '<input type="text" id="title_element" name="about_options[title_element]" value="' . get_option( 'about_options' )[ 'title_element' ] . '" />';
}
// Подзаголовок
function subtitle_callback() {
    echo '<input type="text" id="subtitle_element" name="about_options[subtitle_element]" value="' . get_option( 'about_options' )[ 'subtitle_element' ] . '" />';
}
```

Видно, что `title_callback` и `subtitle_callback` это одно и то же, отличаются только id, я хочу, чтобы функция принимала id в виде переменной, но не знаю как сделать, пробовал так:

```
// Подзаголовок
add_settings_field(
    'subtitle_element',
    'Подзаголовок',
    'subtitle_callback("id")',
    'about_options',
    'about_section'
);
```

Не работает! Как передать туда переменную?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить значение переменной внутрь строки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435981/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @Darth Это не дубликат вопроса. `subtitle_callback` - имя функции обратного вызова. Никакие аргументы этой функции так не запихнуть. Код работать не будет. А как надо - почитайте мой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Третьим параметром у `add_settings_field()` должно быть задано имя функции обратного вызова, и ничего больше. Никакие ухищрения с добавлением в эту строку аргументов работать не будут.

Для передачи дополнительных аргументов в функцию обратного вызова служит пятый аргумент, который должен быть массивом.

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
add_settings_field(
    'subtitle_element',
    'Подзаголовок',
    'subtitle_callback',
    'about_options',
    'about_section',
    array ( 'id' => $id ),
);

function field_callback( $arguments ) {
    $id = $arguments['id'];
    //...
}
```

P.S. Почему попытка вставить аргумент в строку с именем функции не сработает. Вызов вашей функции осуществляется такой строкой кода в `wp-admin/includes/template.php`:

```
call_user_func( $field['callback'], $field['args'] );
```

Первым параметром здесь должно быть имя вызываемой функции типа callable. Документация по [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php).

Comment: Спасибо большое!